# Applying cookies to <input>s with js-cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I wish to apply cookies to two inputs' default values.
I am using GitHub's jscookie, and it would be preferable to have the answer using jscookie as well.
I have an input at a default value of zero and I want it to default to the stored cookie for them after the first time answering it. E.g.

```
<input type="text" name="changeme" value="0">
<div id="submit">Submit</div>
```

JavaScript/JQuery with jscookie plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if (Cookies.get("inputval") != undefined) {
                $('input[name="changeme"]').val(Cookies.get("inputval"));
        }
        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
                var inval = $('input[name="changeme"]').val();
                Cookies.set("inputval", inval { expires: 1, path: "" });
        });
});
```

And so after reloading the page I would expect the value to be what was initially entered. The cookies were saved however they weren't applied to the input. I've tried most every variation on the syntax I could think of, nothing has helped. Thanks in advance for the response!

Comment: This is a syntax error: `inval { expires: 1, path: "" }`. Check your console for logs and errors. I guess you're missing a comma, and it should be: `inval, { expires: 1, path: "" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing a syntax error because you have missed a comma:

```
Cookies.set("inputval", inval { expires: 1, path: "" });
                             ^-- missing ',' here
```

Try the following:

```
$(function() {
    if( Cookies.get('inputval') ) 
    {
        $('input[name="changeme"]').val( Cookies.get('inputval') );
    }

    $('#submit').on('click', function() {
        Cookies.set("inputval", $('input[name="changeme"]').val(), { expires: 1, path: "" });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to have worked well however I added a second input and adjusted the code accordingly and suddenly, I put 95 into input1 and 88 into input2, bringing up the inputs again in the same session will lead to them both being 88 and after a reload input1 is 88 and input2 is empty, despite input1's cookie still being 95 and input2's cookie still being 88. Thanks:)

Comment: Nevermind that. For some reason it didn't work as '.click' and I needed an '.on('click')' despite it not being inserted dynamically. Nonetheless, thank you for your response!